# Is there a Scala 3 specific standard library or is it just inherited from Scala 2?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-3

Is it the case that Scala 3 uses all the collections from Scala 2 standard library? (What elements Scala "standard library" consists of?)

Is there any Scala 3 specific "standard library"?

Are there plans to reimplement Scala 2 libraries to Scala 3?

I was looking for an implementation of an immutable list in Scala 3 and I realized that there seems to be no such thing in the [dotty repo](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty).

I was expecting to find an implementation of [Scala 2 list](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala) in the [dotty repo](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty) as well.

Answer (score 4):

The standard library is shared between Scala 3 and Scala 2.13 and is maintained as part of Scala 2.13.

The standard library was refactored / re-engineered such that it only uses language features that exist in both Scala 2.13 and Scala 3.

(Note: when I write "Scala 3" and "Scala 2.13", I mean the *implementations* with those version numbers. The Scala Language Specification does not say anything about how the standard library is implemented.)

Comment: *"The standard library is shared between Scala 3 and Scala 2.13 and is maintained as part of Scala 2.13."* I'm afraid this is not completely accurate because besides Scala 2.13 standard library there is Scala 3 specific part

Comment: *"The Scala Language Specification does not say anything about how the standard library is implemented"* it's worth mentioning that there is chapter 12 of Scala spec "The Scala Standard Library" https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/12-the-scala-standard-library.html

Answer (score 2):

Scala 2.13 standard library is a part of Scala 3 standard library

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.13.10"
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.10/jar

https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.13.x/src/library/scala

> **The Standard Library**
>
> One notable example is the Scala 2.13 library. We have indeed decided
> that the Scala 2.13 library is the official standard library for Scala
> 3.
>
> Let’s note that the standard library is automatically provided by the
> build tool, you should not need to configure it manually.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/compatibility-classpath.html#the-standard-library

But there is also additional Scala 3 specific part of Scala 3 standard library (packages `scala.deriving`, `scala.compiletime`, `scala.quoted`, `scala.reflect`, `scala.runtime`, `scala.util`, `scala.annotation`)

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala3-library_3" % "3.2.2"
```

or

```
"org.scala-lang" %% "scala3-library" % "3.2.2"
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala3-library

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala3-library_3/3.2.2/jar

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/tree/main/library/src/scala

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/125wg5b/why_does_dotty_depend_on_scala_2/